# When is the best time to initialize Twilio Client device with capability token

Tags: android, ios, twilio, background-process, voip

We have tested Twilio client on both iPhone and Android and it works very well. Now the question is whether we should keep the socket alive in the background all the time or wait until our server sends some hints to the client that someone is calling it and then initialize Twilio client Device with capability token. The former works but may consume a lot of power. The latter may not work if Twilio calls before client initialize the device and the incoming event will not fire.

Comment: Not sure about it,

 but I think Socket Connection should remain alive as the issue with the later case i think is that "Server Can't initiate the client-server connection. Server can only listen for incoming connection, client has to initiate the connection by binding to server port."

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I think a lot of this depends on if you are only making outbound calls from the app, or if you also want to accept inbound calls in the app.

If its the former, then I think its OK to lazily create the device only when the user initiates their outbound call and then destroy the device once the all is complete.

If its the latter, then you'll need to create the token earlier *and* possibly also consider that, by default, the token will expire in 1 hour and will need to be reset.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have a problem if my token expired after 1 hour then how to listen app incoming call from twilio. Please help if you have any solution

Comment: We can get token by using `Service`

Comment: @DevinRader I'm getting problem if I implement code of incoming in Service class. It works few times only.